# How to filter object array using an array in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I hope you're having a great day.

This is pretty straight-forward. I have an object array which I want to filter out, with the help of another array. Scenario is illustrated below:

```
var ob_array = [
                  {'a' : 1, 'col_2' : 'abc'},
                  {'a' : 2, 'col_2' : 'xyz'},
                  {'a' : 3, 'col_2' : 'jkl'}
                 ];

var my_array = [1, 2];
```

Expected Output:

```
var my_array = [
                 {'a' : 3, 'col_2' : 'jkl'}
               ]
```

Tried Approaches:

#1:

```
ob_array.filter(function(i){
   my_array.forEach(function(q){
      i['a'] == q
   })
});
```

#2:

```
ob_array.filter(function(i){
   for(var j in my_array){
      i['a'] == j;
   }
});
```

I mostly tend to use filter function because I love it. Thanks for viewing this small query of mine. I appreciate your time and efforts.

Comment: `.filter()` returns a new array, not modifies it in place. And filter returns `true`/`false`. I suggest reading [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on filter which has plenty of examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead of iterating over `my_array`:

```js
var ob_array = [{
    'a': 1,
    'col_2': 'abc'
  },
  {
    'a': 2,
    'col_2': 'xyz'
  },
  {
    'a': 3,
    'col_2': 'jkl'
  }
];

var my_array = [1, 2];

console.log(ob_array.filter(ob => !my_array.includes(ob.a)))
```

Comment: It really surprises that how simple and effective your approach is. Thank you mate.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` and `includes`

```js
var ob_array = [
                  {'a' : 1, 'col_2' : 'abc'},
                  {'a' : 2, 'col_2' : 'xyz'},
                  {'a' : 3, 'col_2' : 'jkl'}
                 ];

var my_array = [1, 2];

const res = ob_array.filter(({a}) => !my_array.includes(a));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Array#filter` takes a predicate i.e. a callback that returns `true` or `false`. if `true` is returned the element is allowed and `false` otherwise.

You are not returning the boolean result from your predicate callback, your code can be modified as below to return false if the element with key `a` exists in `my_array` or true otherwise:

```js
var ob_array = [{
    'a': 1,
    'col_2': 'abc'
  },
  {
    'a': 2,
    'col_2': 'xyz'
  },
  {
    'a': 3,
    'col_2': 'jkl'
  }
];

var my_array = [1, 2];

const res = ob_array.filter(function(i) {
  for (var j of my_array) {
    if (i['a'] === j) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
});

console.log(res);
```

But a more elegant approach exists with the help of `Array#includes`:

```js
var ob_array = [{
    'a': 1,
    'col_2': 'abc'
  },
  {
    'a': 2,
    'col_2': 'xyz'
  },
  {
    'a': 3,
    'col_2': 'jkl'
  }
];

var my_array = [1, 2];

console.log(ob_array.filter(o => !my_array.includes(o.a)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[{'a' : 1, 'col_2' : 'abc'},
              {'a' : 2, 'col_2' : 'xyz'},
              {'a' : 3, 'col_2' : 'jkl'}
             ].filter(function(i){return (i.a!=1 && i.a!=2)})
```

the above code gives the required output.