# Javascript search object array with normal array as source

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i have array like this

```
var listShow = [1, 3]
```

and this

```
[
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'JOHN',
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'JOHNE',
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: 'JOHNW',
}
]
```

And I only want to return array if id value is same as above array, I want result like this

```
[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'JOHN',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'JOHNW',
    }
]
```

Does anyone know how to make the above possible? I've tried using `array.filter` but it doesn't work

Comment: You say `array.filter` doesn't work. Please can you explain how it doesn't work? Perhaps show us the code you've tried?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+search+object+array+using+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: [dupe of dupes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68088158/how-to-filter-object-array-using-an-array-in-js)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var a = [
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'JOHN',
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'JOHNE',
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: 'JOHNW',
}
]
var b = a.filter((item) => listShow.includes(item.id) )

console.log(b)
```